# Connecting step-up DC-DC converters in series

Tags: boost

I need to boost a voltage from 3.6 to 110 V.

I thought of using two stages, one that boosts from 3.6 to 12 V and another from 12 to 110. I have built it but it doesn't work. After the failure I realize that the series connection of the boosters may not be adequate but I don't know how to isolate the output of the first stage or boost. Has anyone done series connection of stand up/boost converters?

**EDITED:**
The topology I've made it's the next, based on your feedback I suppose that the correct term is cascade:

[image]

The output voltage, Vo, is going to use for supply a full H bridge and obten 110V 50Hz

Comment: Welcome! Sounds like your need to develop an isolated DC-DC. At 3.6 V input, you are probably looking at a push-pull type converter.

Comment: You said "in series." But that terminology could be ambiguous in this context. A diagram probably would be helpful here.

Comment: Did you mean "in series" or "cascade"?

Comment: Were they isolated? If not, was the second one rated for >110v output?

Comment: What is the load at 110 VDC? At very low currents it isn't hard to go straight from 3.6 V to 110 VDC.

Comment: As Solomon and Rohat are alluding to, what you're describing is called a cascade connection, not a series connection. Series would be connecting both inputs and both outputs in series, whereas cascade is when you connect the input of one to the output of the other.

Answer (score 1):

How much current do you need at your output? The challenge will be that your input currents on the 3.6V side will be on the order of 30x what you can achieve at the output. If I had to venture a guess, the current demands being made in the 3.6V side are excessive, which is limiting your output power.

On top of that, the less efficient your converter, the worse that ratio will be. Which means that connecting converters in series ('cascade') will probably be less efficient than making a well-designed inverter or flyback circuit direct from 3.6V.

If your current needs are low, a single stage autotransformer boost could do the job.

Comment: Sorry, that was important information. It is a very low consumption application: 110V 50mA.

Thus, if we consider a total efficiency of 85%, 3.6V which is an LFP cell, the 1S3P (it seems silly but there is a reason not to use a serial connection) must provide 6.88W, that is, 1.9A, for below nominal. discharge rate, 1C.

I thought about using a flyback conversion but I couldn't find any cheap autotransformer with a 1:40 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This could *potentially* be done if they are isolated step ups, the isolation separates the ground of the output and allows the converter to have either rail be connected to another rail and a potential generated above or below that rail. For example, you could use a 10V isolated converter to make a positive or negative 10V rail.

Areas that need consideration are max potential of the converter, all converters would need to exceed the max voltage of the system or there may be the possibility of failure.

Comment: I thought about it, but insulated boosts are too expensive for my application. Is there a way to isolate two series-connected stages of non-isolated boosters?

Comment: The gate driver needs to be isolated from the output. In a non-isolated booster, the diode and inductor are connected to Vin, Vout and the switch from the inductor to ground. There isn't anything that blocks the full voltage of the putting the dc dc converters in series. You could potentially do this if you had a boost design that supports floating, most need ground. In addition, both converters components would need to be designed to handle maximum voltages far beyond their rails, which is unusual.